# Suggestion for site structure

Tags: structure

I’ve got the following site structure, but I’m not sure how to manage the grouping/categories.

[image: Structure]

I know that the articles are my only channel, and categories would normally be easy to work out, but I can’t figure out how to make it work with markets and languages.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: I think your first step should be to choose a multi language approach. There are several different options available to choose from. I personally prefer to use Transcribe by EE Harbor.

Comment: Would that handle the market too?

Comment: Yes it would, Transcribe dynamically inserts the language variable into the URL for you, giving you site.com/en/bathrooms, site.com/ru/bathrooms etc